# TailwindCSS: is it possible to remove a box-shadow on print?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, styling

I have a `div` with a classes that look like this `` className={`${cardSelected && 'shadow-factors'} bg-white rounded-md cursor-pointer`} ``

Right now I'm setting up a print version of the page and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow remove this shadow-factors / box-shadow for the printed version with TailwindCSS toolset?

Comment: Yes you can do this with a media query, @media print {your print rules here}. For a more complete answer please post a complete code example to your question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work I had to add the following to the config:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'print': {'raw': 'print'},
        // => @media print { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this being added to config any `print:` statements are working now, including `print:shadow-none`

Answer (score 9):

Yes Tailwind has a modifier `print`, you may look [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#print-styles)

For example - shadow will disappear when printing

```
<div class="shadow-lg print:shadow-none">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: The solution is good for both v2 and v3+. Keep in mind that for TailwindCSS v2, you have to enable print first: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#styling-for-print

Comment: @CornelRaiu actually I use ^4.0.0 and adding this to tailwind config has worked for me and now it is picking up print:shadow-none